# Why do some cars have their radio antennas in the windscreen?

Tags: audio

On some cars now the radio antenna is in the windscreen, however, in my experience the radio has always been rubbish on the car.

They often seem to get a bad FM reception, where other cars get them very well.

All I can see are disadvantages with this idea:

- Hard to repair
- Poor Reception

I can't see anything good about this idea? What is the point of this terrible design choice?

Comment: Are you having a specific problem that you're trying to fix?  If not, this looks like an entirely opinion-based question.  Unless you're comparing a Lacetti with an external antenna and yours with a built-in, this breaks down into "I hate apples! Why wouldn't everyone eat oranges?!"

Comment: @bob. Changed the Question. Downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Now this question is making a general claim without objective data.  There is no way to get a conclusive answer to such an subjective question.  For example, I have a built-in antenna and my radio reception is fine for my purposes.  However, if you were asking "The radio reception in my Lacetti is poor.  How can I improve it?" that would be something we could help you with.

Comment: @rob I have revised the question! The question has nothing to do with my car but the design in general!

Comment: You claim that "radio antenna is in the windscreen" => "Hard to repair & Poor Reception" and that this is a "terrible design choice." Nowhere above do you ask a question about a problem that you're facing. Please refer to the [don't ask](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) portion of the FAQ for some relevant guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They get damaged less (think automatic car washes) and I would say a car looks cleaner with it in the window.

Answer (score 1):

[Noise, vibration, and harshness (NVH)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise,_vibration,_and_harshness) and fuel mileage. Don't have any reference for that but I believe that was the reason giving in the dealer tech publications when this started 10 plus years ago. I am not sure the antenna is to blame for the poor reception though, in my experience it the factory radios that have the poor reception.

Comment: Poor reception is usually down to shoddy antenna wiring and/or poor grounding of the radio.

Comment: @JuannStrauss Yes that can be a cause, but the newer vehicle have poor receivers in the radios. Specifically 2011 - 2014 Ford F450, 2011 - 2014 Chev Tahoes among others. These from the factory don't pick up radio stations as well or at all that other similar older vehicles do, regardless of antenna or grounding. Put an aftermarket radio in these vehicles and no more reception problems. Plugging in aftermarket radio to same antenna and the factory harness.